# Pros and alternatives of swipe side menu in mobile app

Tags: mobile, menu, swipe

I am developing a mobile app, which has a left side menu that can be opened by swiping from left to right in the screen. However, sometimes, when I try to scroll down the content in the main panel, the side menu is accidentally opened, which is kind of annoying, so I'm considering taking over the swipe functionality, and just letting the button to toggle the menu.

Which can be the advantages of having a swipe behavior to open the side menu, other than a fancy look? Is there any other alternative to the button and the left-right swipe, to open the left side menu?

Answer (score 1):

The advantage that I can think of with the swipe is that it's easier to get to when using one hand (either hand).

A button needs a more precise and more specific tap that may be a bit more awkward on some devices in some situations.

But you of course have to weight that against the con you found with it opening when a user intended to use a different gesture.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure there is a signifier that shows the user that such a feature exists.  I used a favorite app of mine for years before I accidentally discovered there was a side-bar menu available with a swipe gesture.

I think the jury is still out over the effectiveness these menus, especially on small mobile devices, since horizontal space is at a premium.